# "30 años y pico" as an english expression?

Tags: phrase-request, translation, numbers

Spaniards we say "30 years (años) y pico" when we refer to a date without precision. Is like to say a number between 30 and 35.

Has this expression got translation to english?

Comment: **About** 30 years, which could be between 25 and 35. Specifically for between 30 to 35 "**a little more than** 30 years" (AmE) or "**a bit more than** 30 years" (BrE) or "30 years **and a bit**" (BrE) would work

Comment: Also **"30 years, give or take"**, but that could mean slightly less or slightly more than 30.

Comment: Also *30 years and then some*

Comment: Or *thirty-some-odd years*.

Comment: Or [_30 or so years_](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#q=%2230+or+so+years%22&safe=off&hl=en&tbm=bks).

Comment: Or just *30-odd years*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally, "circa 30 years" is used as a formal way of saying "roughly/around/about 30 years, give or take, or so, ish."

Webster's describes it as:

> formal
>
> : about or around. "He was born circa 1600."
>
> : at, in, or of approximately —used especially with dates.

Answer (score 4):

"A little over thirty years" is a fairly literal translation of "*30 años y pico*".

Answer (score 2):

*thirty years or more*

*thirtyish* but this, like several other suggested phrases, means *thirty, plus or minus a bit* or *around thirty*

*thirty something* means *thirty to thirty-nine*, that is *in one's thirties*